# How to extract a particular string from the given string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I have strings -

```
[ '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_01-login.feature' ]
[ '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_02-logout.feature' ]
[ '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_03-createaccount.feature' ]
```

I need to extract the string the string `"smoke_xx"`so whatever the number comes along with smoke_, I need to extract it. I tried many options but didnt worked out. I am new to nodejs. Please help.

Comment: *I tried many options but didnt worked out*, please share

Comment: @LawrenceCherone smoke_\s*(\+\d+). As I said I am very new to regex. so I am not sure.

Comment: cool, `/smoke_(\d+)-/gm` for number or `(smoke_(\d+))-` for inc `smoke_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with regex of @Lawrence Cherone and use of [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/match)

```js
[
  '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_01-login.feature',
  '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_02-logout.feature',
  '/home/user/Music/test/project/iit/feature/ABC/release1/PC/en_smoke/smoke_03-createaccount.feature'
].forEach(path => {
  const smoke = path.match(/smoke_\d+/)[0]
  console.log('smoke :', smoke)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work with following regex:
 `(?i)\bsmoke\s*_\s*\d+`
you can check the link to view result: https://regex101.com/r/z8uUTf/2